# Javascript question about arrays and using image src from it anyone can help? (not random img)

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, href, src

I have created some javascript div, a, img elements.
Making my website easier to read instead of spamming the same stuff over and over again.

My problem right now is -->

I need to use href and src links from my array ("src") and add them to my created imgages and links.

So far i have found only one working way to do it with Math...() but i don't want to show the images in random order i want them to be in the order that i have putted them in the array.

This is my code down below i will be happy if anyone helps me out!

I think this can be solved with forEach but i can't figure it out...

```js
var src = ["https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1176&q=80" , 
           "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458966480358-a0ac42de0a7a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80"];

(function () {

  
    function createDiv() {
      
      var boardDiv = document.createElement("div");
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      var img = document.createElement("img");
  
      boardDiv.className = "col-md-6 col-lg-4 item";
      
      
      boardDiv.appendChild(link);
      link.className = "lightbox"
      link.appendChild(img);
      link.href = src[0];
      
      img.className ="img-fluid image scale-on-hover"
      img.src = src[Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length)];
  
      return boardDiv;
    }
  
    function createAndModifyDivs() {
      var board = document.getElementById("image-builder"),
        myDivs = [],
        i = 0,
        numOfDivs = src.length;
        
      for (i; i < numOfDivs; i += 1) {
        myDivs.push(createDiv());
        board.appendChild(myDivs[i]);
      }
    }
  
    createAndModifyDivs();
  
  }());
```

```css
.gallery-block.grid-gallery{
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .heading{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .heading h2{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery a:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .item img{
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .item{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {

  .gallery-block.grid-gallery .scale-on-hover:hover{
    transform: scale(1.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Grid Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <section class="gallery-block grid-gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3>Alexis</h3>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row" id="image-builder">
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </section>

    <div id="board">
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        baguetteBox.run('.grid-gallery', { animation: 'slideIn' });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `createDiv()` function to take in the img src as a parameter and then set it in your for loop. Your code could be cleaned up a bit and I can help with that if you leave a comment but for now I just wanted to answer your initial question.

```js
var src = ["https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1176&q=80" , 
           "https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1176&q=80"];

(function () {

    // Take the image link as a parameter called imgSrc
    function createDiv(imgSrc) {
      
      var boardDiv = document.createElement("div");
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      boardDiv.className = "col-md-6 col-lg-4 item";
      boardDiv.appendChild(link);
      link.className = "lightbox"
      img.className ="img-fluid image scale-on-hover"
      link.appendChild(img);
      // Assuming here you want to link to the image
      link.href = imgSrc;
      // Set the img src
      img.src = imgSrc;
      return boardDiv;
    }
  
    function createAndModifyDivs(elmId) {
      const board = document.getElementById(elmId);
      for (const imgSrc of src) {
        board.appendChild(createDiv(imgSrc));
      }
    }

    const galleries = ['image-builder', 'image-builder-2'];
    for(const gallery of galleries) {
        createAndModifyDivs(gallery);
        baguetteBox.run(`#${gallery}`);
    }

  
  }());
```

```css
.gallery-block.grid-gallery{
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .heading{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .heading h2{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery a:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .item img{
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .item{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {

  .gallery-block.grid-gallery .scale-on-hover:hover{
    transform: scale(1.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Grid Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <section class="gallery-block grid-gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3>Alexis</h3>
            </div>
            
            <div class="gallery" id="image-builder">
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </section>
    
    <section class="gallery-block grid-gallery">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <h3>Other</h3>
            </div>
            
            <div class="gallery" id="image-builder-2">
            </div>

        </div>
        
    </section>

    <div id="board">
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.10.0/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First - Thank you very much!
It is working but now i can't switch between the images when i click on them on full screen. Any fix for that? And i will be very thankful if you can make that code clearer i am trying to make it but i kinda lack the skills.

Comment: I've updated the code to remove a lot of unnecessary stuff. Also, to get the box to show I had to pass the parent element id where you're adding the images to the `baguetteBox.run('#image-builder');`

Comment: @KrasimirKanov The other change I had to make was to remove that second photo because something is wrong with the link that the baguetteBox doesn't like it.

Comment: Well now there is another problem you removed the div, link, img classes and now the website is not responsive... + the function returns the link wich makes the images ultra big. I am trying to keep it responsive and working. Would you mind to check the code again?

Comment: @KrasimirKanov I've put the classes back. I just removed them to figure out the issue with the lightbox/gallery.

Comment: It is working 100% everything is fixed i know you went thru a lot of trouble trying to fix my coding but you did it and i am very proud and thankful of your help! It seems that the array doesn't like unsplash image links it works perfect with links from discord. Now my final request to you is can you make a second div category <h3> Forest <h3> and it will use another function with another array of links after the end of the first category images. I tried reusing the first function with different names but i didn't make it to show any divs after the <h3>.

Comment: I've updated it to use multiple galleries.

Comment: Well it works when i open it here but when i try on live server with VSC it doesn't + how can i add another array of images to the second gallery cuz right now it uses the first array src but i want it to use another array src2 for example. You already helped a lot so i am happy with what i got. I don't want to be annoying so thank you again. If you want to finish this challenge it will be amazing cuz i will be launching my first website with your help i will definetely mention you on it if you want.

Comment: No worries, and I don't need credit thank you though. For a second set of images you would just follow the original answer and add another parameter on the `createAndModifyDivs` function that takes in an array of image urls to iterate over. For it not working locally you might want to wrap the galleries in a function that is called on `window.onload` like `window.onload = () => { for(const gallery in galleries) { .... } };`

Comment: I reused the function with different name and the problem was actually that i had to just swap baguettebox.js with app.js. Now both gallery work with different source arrays. Thank you again for everything!

Answer (score 0):

You only have to make these two changes, now you will pass the src as a parameter of `createDiv()` (look for the comments)

In App.js

```js
var src = [
  "https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1176&q=80",
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458966480358-a0ac42de0a7a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",
];

(function () {
  //ADD A PARAMETER TO THE FUNCTION HERE
  function createDiv(img_src) {
    var boardDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    boardDiv.className = "col-md-6 col-lg-4 item";

    boardDiv.appendChild(link);
    link.className = "lightbox";
    link.appendChild(img);
    link.href = src[0];

    img.className = "img-fluid image scale-on-hover";
    img.src = img_src;

    return boardDiv;
  }

  function createAndModifyDivs() {
    var board = document.getElementById("image-builder"),
      myDivs = [],
      i = 0,
      numOfDivs = src.length;

    for (i; i < numOfDivs; i += 1) {
      //PASS THE SRC OF THE DIRECT IMAGE AS PARAMETER HERE
      myDivs.push(createDiv(src[i]));
      board.appendChild(myDivs[i]);
    }
  }

  createAndModifyDivs();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed the img problem! Good job! But what about the links? when i put img_src param for the links it works but when i open them on full screen i loose the sliding efect to change the pictures.